# Server does not load index.php

Tags: lamp

I have just installed the lamp-server package on a new ubuntu 12.10 installation. It went fine.

I tested on localhost/ and got the expected response.

The I created an index.php file

Loading localhost/index.php works fine but loading
localhost/ does not. Here a download of a ~ file is started.

I tried creating a .htaccess file contain only this line in the /var/www:
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive.

Try putting this in your default site configuration:

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php
```